# how to do multiple drill down group by on dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get statistics on my datasets,

example this is my dataset: (my real dataset has more columns - this is an example)

```
FirstName LastName Country  City    Neighborhood

Donald    Trump    England  London  Blackheath
Bill      Gates    England  London  Archway
Donald    Duck     England  York    BadgerHill
Donald    Duck     Germany  Berlin  Friedrichshain
```

my statistics will show how many people live in each town, drill down to group by city, Neighborhood - according to defined filters

for example, if these are my filters:

```
FILTERS = [
        {'key': 'address', 'labels': ['Country', 'City', 'Neighborhood']},
        {'key': 'name', 'labels': ['FirstName', 'LastName]},
    ]
```

the result will be:

```
{
    "address": [
        {"value": "England", "count": 3,"items": [
                {"value": "London", "count": 2, "items": [
                    {"value": "Blackheath","count": 1},
                    {"value": "Archway","count": 1}
                ]},
                {"value": "York", "count": 1, "items": [
                    {"value": "BadgerHill", "count": 1}
                ]}
        ]},
        {"value": "Germany", "count": 1, "items": [
            {"value": "Berlin", "count": 1, "items": [
                {"value": "Friedrichshain", "count": 1}
            ]}
        ]}
    ],
    "name": [
        {"value": "Donald", "count": 3, "items": [
            {"value": "Trump", "count": 1},
            {"value": "Duck", "count": 2}
        ]},
        {"value": "Bill", "count": 1, "items": [
            {"value": "Gates", "count": 1}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

in my ui - this will be shown as drill down filters, that the client can choose:

[image]

my question is: can I do this using pandas? I manage to get the result using some recursive loop on my data, but I would like to use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I did it:

```
all_data_df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
for filt in FILTERS:
    selected_keys = filt.get('labels')
    results2[filt.get('key')] = get_options_recursive_pandas(all_data_df[selected_keys], selected_keys)


def get_options_recursive_pandas(data, columns) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    results = []
    if columns:
        current_column = columns[0]
        value_counts = data[current_column].value_counts()
        for label, count in value_counts.items():
            filt = (data[current_column] == label) 
            results.append({
                'value': label,
                'count': count,
                'items': get_options_recursive_pandas(data[filt], columns[1:]),
            })

    return results
```